# What is proper way to Center a Label element using CSS in a asp.net .master page

Tags: css, asp.net, http, label, center

I am trying to put together a asp.net webforms website for a church fellowship organization and I am having to learn to work with building this website from scratch using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web's Empty asp.net Website Template and since I have never done websites before, I am having to search through the Internet for examples, most of my programming experience comes from C# and I just don't seem to be able to find a solution for this.

Anyway my problem is that I can't figure out how to Center a asp.net Label on the SiteMasterPage.master

```
<div class="header1">
  <br />
  <br />
  <h1 class="auto-style1">Calvary Christian FellowshipGA, Inc.</h1>
  <div style="align-items: center">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="ccfgaLabel" ForeColor="#0066FF" Text="Calvary Christian FellowshipGA, Inc."></asp:Label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <p>
    Informational Text here.
  </p>
  <br />
  <p>
    More Informational Text here.
  </p>
</div>
```

I've tried a couple things the above being the latest, the only thing I've found that actually worked was to use:

```
<center>
  MY Label
</center>
```

the only issue with this use of 'center' is that I get the 'center' is deprecated warning.  I would like to be able to do this correctly, could someone give me some suggestions how to get this done.

I tried the following from a .css file.

```
.ccfgaLabel
{
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 230px;
    /*margin-left: 10px;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The only thing that seemed to work in it were the

```
width: 230px;
```

and

```
margin-left: 10px;
```

I would like to set this up inside the css file since this is all gonna be on a MasterPage.

*Edit:  I should point out that the only reason I decided to try a Label was that I wanted a Bordered and Shaded, Box aspect around the Text and I hadn't yet tried to see if bordering and shading was possible just around specific Text centered in the middle of the page.

Comment: In your wrapper div, instead of `align-items` you should use `text-align: center`

Comment: yea that did it, I had tried using text-align: center in other areas and it didn't work, so I just assumed it wouldn't do it in the div wrapper I created.  Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Would you consider using a CSS "framework" such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)? It could be helpful to use such, to speed up your development, and also to _learn_ (by looking at the CSS source and seeing how "its done", cross browser, etc.).

Comment: Ok @roadmaster, posted as the answer...

Comment: @EdSF, I don't know anything about Bootstrap and I haven't attempted anything Cross Browser yet.  Do you know of any Links to anything explaining what CSS Bootstrap is?  If not i'll google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since the comment worked, here's the posted answer.

Instead of your `align-items` that you set on the wrapper div, use the `text-align` property, that is used to specify the alignment of inline content:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="ccfgaLabel" ForeColor="#0066FF" Text="Calvary Christian FellowshipGA, Inc."></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Though I recommend you not to set it as an inline style. Rather, give the div an id or a class and leave the property on the stylesheet.

[**MDN text-align docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Comment: This does not work for me.  Did something change since then?

Comment: Left justified.  If I use the non-supported <center></center> tags, it centers.  I've tried your solution, also "align-content" and "align-items", as part of the class="col-sm-" as a separate div.  You'd think there'd be an easy replacement if they wanted to get rid of the center tags.